# Programmatically access Azure DevOps variable groups without using REST api

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops

Is there a way to programmatic access the Azure DevOps variable groups by using C# class wrappers rather than the REST API provide here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0][1]

Comment: [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DistributedTask library. Here is an example code fragment

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi;

// Connect to Azure DevOps Services
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
TaskAgentHttpClient TaskAgentClient = connection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();

// get variable groups
List<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.VariableGroup> vargrps = TaskAgentClient.GetVariableGroupsAsync(project: projectName).Result;
```